# C# Reading from file, removing numbers and special characters and add to hashtable

Tags: c#

The task is to read from a file, retrieve words (no numbers or special characters) and adding it to a hash table. If the same word (key) already exist in the hash table, update the frequency of the word(value) +1.

So far in the code blow, all text is retrieved from the file including words with numbers and special characters into a string array "words".
I would like to update the values based on a regex to only keep words with letters, in lowercase.

I have tried the regex in all different ways but it does not work. The Split() method only allows individual characters to be removed. (eventually, this code will need to be applied to 200 files with unknown amount of special characters and numbers).

Is there a clean way to read the file, save only words and omit special characters and numbers?

this is what i have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String myLine;
            String[] words;
            Hashtable hashT = new Hashtable();
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("C:\\file including numbers and spacial charecters.txt");

            while ((myLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                words = myLine.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                string pattern = @"^[a - z] +$";
                Regex term = new Regex(pattern);

                for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
                    words[i] = Regex.Replace(words[i], term, "");

                    if (hashT.ContainsKey(words[0]))
                    {
                        hashT[words[i]] = double.Parse(hashT[words[i]].ToString()) + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hashT.Add(words[i], 1.00);
                    }
                }

                foreach (String word in hashT.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(word + " " + hashT[words]);
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: New User Tip: f you ask 1 question at a time, your far more likely to get a response

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //file content read form your file
            string fileContent = @"Hello Wor1d
fun f1nd found
";
            //split file content to lines
            string[] line = fileContent.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Regex r = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+");

            List<string> matchesList = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                //split line to string, like Hello Wor1d => string[]{ Hello, Wor1d }
                string[] lineData = line[i].Split(' ');

                for (int j = 0; j < lineData.Length; j++)
                {
                    string str = lineData[j];
                    //get matches form string
                    //if count == 0, string is not include words
                    //if count > 1 string is have some not words, because Wor1d have 2 matches => Wor and d
                    if (r.Matches(str).Count == 1)
                    {
                        matchesList.Add(str);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{matchesList[i]} is ok");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```